# Barplot in ggplot does not conform to command 'position=position_dodge()'

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am plotting a dataframe using ggplot.

The dataframe is this:

```
   cluster      Profession        means
1        1   Bank_Employee 4.151786e-02
2        2   Bank_Employee 1.150637e-02
3        1     Businessman 2.089286e-02
4        2     Businessman 2.160738e-02
5        1          Doctor 3.321429e-02
6        2          Doctor 2.968819e-02
7        1        Engineer 2.535714e-02
8        2        Engineer 1.703996e-02
9        1          Farmer 5.267857e-03
10       2          Farmer 8.168643e-03
11       1       Housewife 1.151786e-02
12       2       Housewife 3.293808e-02
13       1     Independent 8.482143e-03
14       2     Independent 1.203338e-02
15       1          Lawyer 5.928571e-02
16       2          Lawyer 3.276241e-02
17       1         Missing 4.787500e-01
18       2         Missing 2.942468e-01
19       1       Pensioner 8.928571e-03
20       2       Pensioner 3.560826e-01
21       1  PrSec_Employee 7.205357e-02
22       2  PrSec_Employee 3.987703e-02
23       1 PubSec_Employee 6.133929e-02
24       2 PubSec_Employee 6.473430e-02
25       1   Self_Employed 6.883929e-02
26       2   Self_Employed 4.198507e-02
27       1         Student 3.357143e-02
28       2         Student 8.783487e-05
29       1       Tradesman 1.339286e-02
30       2       Tradesman 1.431708e-02
31       1      Unemployed 1.544643e-02
32       2      Unemployed 7.817303e-03
33       1       OtherProf 4.214286e-02
34       2       OtherProf 1.510760e-02
```

The command is the following:

```
ggplot(data=dfcards13ml, aes(x=Profession, y=means, fill= cluster)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  labs(title="Proportions of Professions in each Cluster",
       x="Professions", y = "Mean")
```

The output is this:

[Barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uf0z.png)

As you can see the barplot is stacked, although I have prescribed in the code to be 'dodge'.

Can you explain it?  What should I change in my code?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: They are in fact not stacked, but appear to be so because they are overlapping. Compare to `position = "stack"` and notice the y-axis. Also, compare to `position = "jitter"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a group mapping:

```
ggplot(data=dfcards13ml, 
       aes(x=Profession, y=means, fill= cluster, group = cluster)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
labs(title="Proportions of Professions in each Cluster", 
     x="Professions", y = "Mean")
```

Comment: I changed the code to fill = as.factor(cluster) and it worked